# 5V protection circuits

Tags: circuit-protection, 5v, solar-charge-controller

For my project, I'm using [this solar shield](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Solar_Charger_Shield_V2.2/) in order to use some solar panels and a battery to power my Arduino.  In order to protect the solar shield (where the maximum solar input is 6V) I would like to add a protection circuit between the solar panel and the input shield in order to avoid burning the shield.

This is because, reading the [SP page info](https://www.seeedstudio.com/1W-Solar-Panel-80X100.html), during particular summer days the voltage could be more than 5.5V (also 10V).

Do you know some protection circuits in order to provide 5V as maximum voltage?

I'm not expert, in case, do you know any "ready to use" solution?

Comment: There are basically two approaches: one is to waste current so the solar panel's voltage drops below 5.5V (a shunt regulator), and the other is to block voltage so the Arduino only gets the one you need (a series regulator). The first option is usually bad because it drains your batteries / inflates your power bill, but for a solar panel it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could employ a 5 V Zener diode. Just be sure to limit the current through it, or it will be destroyed.  That's not a ready-to use solution: it's a change to the circuit.

Comment: Zener protection barely works when power is involved. You'd need a zener diode with very high voltage and power rating and the current limiting resistor will waste a lot of power, leaving only few power for charging the battery.

Answer (score 0):

If the load is above 1kΩ and the input voltage is withing some range you can have something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWQE3y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The trouble with this circuit is that the load  current dissipates waste power in the potentiometer.

Comment: I thought that this was a frequent problem.. is not there any solution ready to purchase?

Comment: @Safari the solution is to use a solar charger that supports a sufficiently high input voltage. There's no good way using passive components, you need some kind of switch-mode regulator.